# Particle rotation normal issue with particle orientation

Tags: particles, normals

Is there a way to get the particles in the correct orientation to the emitter and not rotated at varying angles? (see image)

eg. butterflies sitting on a cube's surface.

My relevant settings are:

- Emit From > Faces
- Rotation > Initial Orientation > Normal
- Render > Group > Rotation (selected)

v2.73

In the image example it looks like the normal interpolates between each adjoining face's normal to rotate the particle. I'm also noticing that when the object rotates the particles spin which is also an unwanted effect. Is the normal acting as the axis for a quaternion?

[image]

I cannot recreate this interpolation problem with a cube primitive (gives correct behavior) but when rotating the cube (emitter), the faces with the z-axis, causes the particles to move. cube created in v.276.

[image]

Comment: Its good that you have a question with a question mark (?) at the beginning of your statement. I do find the question to be unclear. Others may find it otherwise. I am suggesting you examine your question and make it more clear. [correct orientation] which you wrote could mean anything. I may make guesses in until that time. You have a group [panels] as particles, so that group could contain may different planes at different angles. You can tell the reader the contents of [panels] rather them encouraging them to guess

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger - edited for clarity. Ty

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions below?

Comment: I did try atomicbezierslinger suggestion and I couldn't get the desired or consistent results. But all results continued to have unwanted particle movement when the emitter rotated... might try keyed particles and post a result.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger - still got some weird particle movement with emitter rotation.

Comment: Your particle system setup is made to catch roatation of dupli objects (in the Render rollout > Rotation check); probably particles get original objects' rotation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Some Suggestions

- I have experienced some latency and strange behavior with Particles.  Yet I do not want to produce a defect report.  Sometimes I have closed and reopened file.  Move the timeline to frame 0 and switched from Vertex to Face to Volume emission.  I have been very hesitant to inquire about this.  I have felt this latency has suddenly function as expected.  Misleading latency.  Could be interpreted as superstitious.
- For the text to mesh.  Edit Mode, Use vertex remove doubles.
- Object Mode,  Remesh Modifier and Apply.  So your faces are even size and no tedious hand modeling.
- Edit Mode, With the faces from above in Faces Mode.  Select all Faces.  Sort Elements Randomize.
- Note my Emission Panel Setting are a bit different than yours.
- For the current settings and the simple scaled cube ... a rotation in EDIT mode can rotate the particle.

[image]

Image above shows the results of Remesh Modifier with Apply.

Other Edits May Follow.